# 404 on Jekyll site published under GitHub organization am I doing something wrong?

Tags: github, jekyll

On my standard GitHub account I manage to view Jekyll site with `username.GitHub.io`.  I then went on and published another GitHub Jekyll site under `github organization`  but when I access it with `organization-name.GitHub.io` I get `404 page not found`.  Is it something which is not supposed to work or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you push your repository to a new repository called `organization-name.github.io`? Are you using a `CNAME` file?

Comment: Always good to have a real url to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
I have `moved` a `jekyll` `repository` into an `organization`.  I never did a new `commit` to that organization.  I had to perform a dummy `commit` into that organization in order to trigger a build and it works!